# Word2Vec with ConvNetSharp

Tags: word2vec, convnetsharp

I have been trying to implement word2vec using ConvNetSharp. I was able to produce a basic version of the algorithm using Relu on a hidden layer but it is not very accurate and I would like to implement a more faithful (and accurate) version of the algorithm using the ConvNetSharp flow API. Any help much appreciated!

```
            var corpus = new List<string> {
              "king is a strong man",
              "queen is a wise woman",
              "boy is a young man",
              "girl is a young woman",
              "prince is a young king",
              "princess is a young queen",
              "man is strong",
              "woman is pretty",
              "prince is a boy will be king",
              "princess is a girl will be queen" };

        corpus = RemoveStopWords(corpus);

        //build the list of words
        var words = corpus.SelectMany(s => s.Split(' ')).Distinct().ToList();

        //build training data based on the words around the focus word
        var WINDOW_SIZE = 2;
        var data = new List<(string, string)>();
        foreach (var sentence in corpus)
        {
            var split = sentence.Split();
            var count = 0;
            foreach (var word in split)
            {
                var start = count - WINDOW_SIZE;
                var end = count + WINDOW_SIZE + 1;
                if (start < 0)
                {
                    start = 0;
                }
                if (end > split.Length)
                {
                    end = split.Length;
                }
                for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
                {
                    var neighbor = split[i];
                    if (neighbor != word)
                    {
                        data.Add((word, neighbor));
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
        }

        var inputs = new List<double[]>();
        var labels = new List<double[]>();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            inputs.Add(OneHotEncoding(item.Item1, words));
            labels.Add(OneHotEncoding(item.Item2, words));
        }

        //setup the net
        var DIMENSIONS = 4;
        var net = new ConvNetSharp.Core.Net<double>();
        var width = words.Count;
        var batchSize = inputs.Count;
        net.AddLayer(new InputLayer(width, 1, 1));
        net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(DIMENSIONS));
        net.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());
        net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(width));
        net.AddLayer(new SoftmaxLayer(width));

        //train
        var trainer = new AdamTrainer<double>(net) { LearningRate = 0.01, BatchSize = batchSize };
        var netx = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(width, 1, 1, batchSize));
        var hotLabels = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, width, batchSize));
        for (var i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
            var label = labels[i];
            for (var w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                var input = inputs[i][w];
                var output = label[w];
                netx.Set(w, 0, 0, i, input);
                hotLabels.Set(0, 0, w, i, output);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            trainer.Train(netx, hotLabels);
            Console.WriteLine($"loss {trainer.Loss}");
        }

        //extract 'embedings' from hidden layer into a results dictionary 
        var hiddenLayer = net.Layers[1];
        var vecs = hiddenLayer.GetParametersAndGradients();
        var v = vecs[0].Volume.Storage;
        var results = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var index = words.IndexOf(word);
            var d = new List<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++)
            {
                var item = v.Get(0, 0, index, i);
                d.Add(item);
            }
            results.Add(word, d);
        }

        //try to use the embedings to perform operations in word space
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n(king - man) + woman");
        PrintNearest(Add(Subtract(results["king"], results["man"]), results["woman"]), results);
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nqueen + young");
        PrintNearest(Add(results["queen"], results["young"]), results);
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nman + young");
        PrintNearest(Add(results["man"], results["young"]), results);

    private string[] NearestList(List<double> find, Dictionary<string, List<double>> results)
    {
        return results.OrderBy(r => Distance(find, r.Value)).Select(r => r.Key).ToArray();
    }

    public static double Distance(List<double> a, List<double> b)
    {
        var dot = 0.0d;
        var mag1 = 0.0d;
        var mag2 = 0.0d;
        for (var n = 0; n < a.Count; n++)
        {
            dot += a[n] * b[n];
            mag1 += Math.Pow(a[n], 2);
            mag2 += Math.Pow(b[n], 2);
        }

        return dot / (Math.Sqrt(mag1) * Math.Sqrt(mag2)) *-1;
    }

    private double[] OneHotEncoding(string word, List<string> words)
    {
        var result = new double[words.Count];
        result[words.IndexOf(word)] = 1;
        return result;
    }

    private List<string> RemoveStopWords(List<string> corpus)
    {
        var stop_words = new List<string> { "is", "a", "will", "be" };
        var results = new List<string>();
        foreach (var text in corpus)
        {
            var newText = string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Where(w => !stop_words.Contains(w)));
            results.Add(string.Join(" ", newText));
        }
        return results;
    }

    private void PrintNearest(List<double> find, Dictionary<string, List<double>> results)
    {
        foreach (var r in NearestList(find, results))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ans = {r}");
        }
    }

    private List<double> Add(List<double> a, List<double> b)
    {
        return a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i + j).ToList();
    }

    private List<double> Subtract(List<double> a, List<double> b)
    {
        return a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i - j).ToList();
    }
```

I have attempted a flow implementation but I am struggling to get the shape dimensions to align:

```
            var net = new ConvNetSharp<double>();
        var x = net.PlaceHolder("x");
        var y = net.PlaceHolder("y");
        // hidden layer: which represents word vector eventually
        var w1 = net.Variable(BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.Random(new Shape(ONE_HOT_DIM, EMBEDING_DIM)), "w1", true);
        var b1 = net.Variable(BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.Random(new Shape(1)), "b1", true);
        var hidden_layer = net.MatMult(x, w1) + b1;

        // output layer
        var w2 = net.Variable(BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.Random(new Shape(EMBEDING_DIM, ONE_HOT_DIM)), "w2", true);
        var b2 = net.Variable(BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.Random(new Shape(1)), "b2", true);
        var prediction = net.Softmax(net.Reshape(net.MatMult(hidden_layer, w2) + b2, new Shape(ONE_HOT_DIM)));

        // loss function: cross entropy
        var loss = net.CrossEntropyLoss(prediction, y);

        // training operation
        var batchSize = inputs.Count;
        var optimizer = new AdamOptimizer<double>(net, 0.01f, 0.9f, 0.999f, 1e-08f);

        using (var session = new Session<double>())
        {
            session.Differentiate(loss);
            double currentCost = 0;
            do
            {
                var xx = BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(ONE_HOT_DIM));
                var yy = BuilderInstance<double>.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(ONE_HOT_DIM));
                for (var i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
                {
                    var input = inputs[i];
                    var label = labels[i];
                    for (var w = 0; w < ONE_HOT_DIM; w++)
                    {
                        xx.Set(w, 0, 0, 0, input[w]);
                        yy.Set(w, 0, 0, 0, label[w]);
                    }

                    var dico = new Dictionary<string, Volume<double>> { { "x", xx }, { "y", yy } };
                    var result = session.Run(loss, dico);
                    currentCost = Math.Abs(result.ToArray().Sum());
                    Console.WriteLine($"cost: {currentCost}");
                    session.Run(optimizer, dico);

                }
            } while (currentCost > 1e-5);
        }

        var v = hidden_layer.Result;
```